# Can no longer run postgresql as a service in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

When I switched on my computer today the postgresql service suddenly wouldn't start. Its been working fine since I installed. It runs fine by running the command below as the user postgres

/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main -l logfile start

But it just won't start as a service anymore and there is zero logging in postgresql or syslog. How can I troubleshoot this without any logging?

Comment: can you paste output after using **-c** or **--core-file** option with pg_ctl?

Comment: It just started working fine again the next day after I boot up my machine and I have no idea what transpired. So I guess the output is of no use anymore. Suppose I will have to wait to see if problem arises again.